# Symfony2 form: no empty choice

Tags: forms, symfony, constraints

Building a Symfony2 form with choices, there is a option "empty value", to set the text related to the empty choice.

However, I want to set my choice field as mandatory, so the empty value should be displayed but no choosen. Using the empty or null constraints, there is no error when the user send the "" value. How should this be done?

Comment: How are you setting your choice field as mandatory by the way - are you using the form field attribute `required  => true`? If you are, you should note that this is a flag to enable the HTML5 `required` attribute. It's not the same as constraint validation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#required

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `NotBlank()` validation constraint to the appropriate property in the form's underlying entity.

How you do this depends on whether you are using annotations or yaml for your validation definitions.

There is some information about the validator here:

> http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This problem is that this validator doesn't seem to work with choices. I also tried the "choice" constraint => It excludes unwanted data but no empty values

Comment: Are your choices coming from a reference table/related entity? If you update your question with some snippets of your entity/form code we can try to figure out what exactly is going on.

Comment: There's also the `@Assert\Choice()` validator.

Comment: Unfortunaly, I have to set the constraints dynamically, i.a.
$params['constraints'][] = NotEmpty(...) then $formBuilder->add('name', 'choice', $params); I have noticed another strange behavior : when I add this validator to text fields, the validator is applied (I can see it with xdebug) but with choices the validator is never called... In order to bypass, I tried to do my own validator but the behavior is the same (only called from text and not from choices)

Comment: @Rolintocour did you able to fix not blank validation?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for inconvenience, I had a listener that overwrote the constraint I set before for choices only, that's why it didn't work like it should...